# Mysql, how to order by the first number in a set of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to order by a field that contains a set of numbers.  Lets say a table named `TEST` contains `ID, NAME, QUADS` with `QUADS` as follows.

```
95,273,212,405
717,450,771,504
391,176,646,272
```

This are the results I am getting with a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY QUADS
391,176,646,272
717,450,771,504
95,273,212,405
```

These are the results I am looking to get

```
95,273,212,405
391,176,646,272
717,450,771,504
```

I am only interested in the first number in the set for "order".  Figure it might be possible with a substring to the comma but not sure how to do that in MySQL.

Comment: can you show us your table structure and what is the query you already have?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not just unusual, but a bad idea: you should (probably) not have multiple values in one column (without a good reason), as that contradicts the principle of normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from test
order by cast(substring_index(quads,',',1) as unsigned)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function.

```
... order by substring_index(x_field,',',1)
```

This extracts the text in `x_field` up to the first occurrence of the comma delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
select QUADS, 0+QUADS as S from TEST order by S
```

0+QUADS will convert your string to int and will use for it just the first digits sequence before "," which is actually what you want.